# Need event when iOS app terminated by the user

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Need to implemented any type of event like local notification or log on App terminate. It should call every time when app is terminated and if app is put into the background for 1 day then also it should called.

I have tried following ways

**applicationWillTerminate** :- It will only called when user directly kill the app without putting app in background

**sceneDidDisconnect:** - It is called when user put app in background and then terminate but is called only one time. if i again launch app and do the same steps it is not getting called.